# Summation Problem?

Tags: summation

It's been a while since I've had to do anything like this so my skills are super rusty.  Someone at the office asked me if I knew a formula and I came back empty.

I have $115$ numbers ($n$) that sum to $935$. Each number is less than the previous by a percentage ($x$).

$x$ never changes.
$n > n -1$.

The problem is what are these $155$ numbers.

Is this solvable. I feel like either the max or min number is needed before it can be solved.

Comment: What is the question (what has to be solved)???

Comment: yeah sry.  What are the 115 numbers

Comment: Let $y$ denote the initial (largest) number, then: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{114}y\cdot\left(\frac{100-x}{100}\right)^n=935$. This would be possible if either the value of $x$ or the value of $y$ were known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second sentence says that your sum is

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{114} a \left ( 1-\frac{x}{100} \right )^k$$

for unknown numbers $a,x$. This is a so-called geometric series, and there is a formula for it:

$$S=a  \frac{1-\left ( 1-\frac{x}{100} \right )^{115}}{\frac{x}{100}}$$

Now your first sentence says $S=935$. This is not enough information to find both $a$ and $x$, at least if you only assume they are real numbers. Basically any additional piece of information (the first number, the last number, the 37th number, whatever) would allow you to solve the problem, but this alone does not.

Comment: OK. I thought so, though the formula needed escaped me.  Thank you.

Comment: nice.........+1